# How to download OneDrive files using Node JS

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-active-directory, onedrive

In our team, a person has uploaded a lot of files in his OneDrive folder. He has shared the links with me and I can access the files from my account. Now I want to download all the files and store them on my computer. I am trying to do this using node js but failed

so far I have tried these things:

1. created an application on Azure and authenticated with the client ID, and tenant ID, secret ID using `@azure/msal-node`
2. Tried oauth2 and tried to authenticate but failed

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62732449/download-file-from-onedrive-using-rest-api https://www.example-code.com/nodejs/onedrive_download_to_file.asp https://medium.com/@oahmad33898/integration-of-onedrive-storage-with-node-js-9b8815a2ad15 check this

Answer (score 0):

> **Note** that: To download the OneDrive files, the application must have **`Files.ReadWrite.All`** application API permission granted. Refer this [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-get-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions)

I created an **Azure AD application** and granted below API permissions:

[image]

> **He has shared the links with me and I can access the files from my account.**

***As you have the shared URLs, you have to encode the sharing URL:***

```cs
string sharingUrl = "https://xxx-my.sharepoint.com/:t:/g/personal/xxx_onmicrosoft_com/ETRFRavc8-5PlKpZ3Gn2KrgBXFxdjAfOFzUXytt2bO****";
string base64Value = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sharingUrl));
string encodedUrl = "u!" + base64Value.TrimEnd('=').Replace('/', '_').Replace('+', '-');

Console.WriteLine(encodedUrl);
```

[image]

Now generate the **access token** using Client Credential flow:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
grant_type:client_credentials
```

[image]

Refer these [**MsDoc1**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/msal-node/confidentialclientapplication?view=msal-js-latest#@azure-msal-node-confidentialclientapplication-acquiretokenbyclientcredential) and [**MsDoc2**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/quickstart-console-app-nodejs-acquire-token) to generate access token using **`@azure/msal-node`**.

**To download the OneDrive file**, make use of below Microsoft Graph API query:

```json
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/shares/AboveEncodedSharingUrl/driveItem
```

[image]

When you do **ctrl+click** on **`@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl`**, the file will be downloaded:

[image]

**To do it in node.js**, make use of below code snippet:

```js
const options = {
authProvider,
};
const client = Client.init(options);
let driveItem = await client.api('/shares/EncodedSharingUrl/driveItem')
.get();
```

Refer the below **MsDoc** to download the file using the Microsoft Graph APIs:

[Download a file - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-get-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#http-request)